# Is a subset of a vector space never linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone explain me something, I'm not sure if it's a question to be asked in here, if it's not I'm sorry and I'll delete the post.

So I read in my linear algebra book that a subset of a vector space should always contain the zero vector, or it wouldn't be an subset, however as I continued reading in my book and I came across linear (in)dependence. Here they said that when a subset contains the zero vector it's never linear independent. So that would mean that a subset is never linear independent.

I'm probably misunderstanding something, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: You're mixing *subset* and *subspace*.

Comment: Subset or **subspace**? There's a difference.

Comment: Yes I'm indeed mixing it up, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have some confusions that I will clarify for you.

Let $(V,+,.)$ be a vector space, with scalars from a field $F$.  Then a subset $S$ of $V$ is called a subspace if $(S,+,.)$ is a vector space, with scalars from field $F$.

Note: The zero vector is necessary for a set to be a vector space.

The other part of your question is about dependent and independent set of vectors.

The subset $H$ of a vector space $V$ is called dependent if there exists a vector in it that can be written as a linear combination of the others, and it is called linearly independent if no vector in it can be written as a linear combination of the others.

Any subset of vectors in $V$ that contains the zero vector is dependent because:
$0_{V}=0.v_{1}$
$(v_{1}$ is some vector in $H)$.